# How to assign info window in polyline using google map api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

My Scenario. I have five markers and connecting to the polyline. When I click marker a to marker b between polyline it will show an info window. In the info, the window has marker a address and marker b address. I achieved this scenario using islocationedge concept in google Maps API. but this concept I facing an issue. when I click marker a to marker b polyline it will show marker b and marker c address because segment polyline I used. I need how to assign an info window in an individual polyline.

**My code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Google Map</h1>

<div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>

<script>
function myMap() {
var mapProp= {
  center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
  zoom:5,
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
var goldenGatePosition = [{lat: 30.2179130,lng: -81.5628150, address: 'Tamil Nadu'},{lat: 30.2179140,lng: -81.5627480, address: 'India'},{lat:30.2177650,lng:-81.5629100,address: 'America'},{lat: 30.2844080,lng: -81.5633900, address: 'Tamil Nadu'},{lat: 30.2843840,lng: -81.5633890, address: 'Tamil Nadu'}];
for(let i=0;i<goldenGatePosition.length;i++){
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: goldenGatePosition[i],
            map: map,
            title: 'Golden Gate Bridge'
            });
}
var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path:goldenGatePosition,
  strokeColor:"#0000FF",
  strokeOpacity:0.8,
  strokeWeight:2
});
flightPath.setMap(map);
let poly, geodesicPoly;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var codeStr=''
google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath, 'click', function(event) {
      // make polyline for each segment of the input line
      for (var i = 0; i < this.getPath().getLength() - 1; i++) {
        var segmentPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: [this.getPath().getAt(i), this.getPath().getAt(i + 1)]
        });
        console.log(segmentPolyline)
        // check to see if the clicked point is along that segment
        if (google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(event.latLng, segmentPolyline, 10e-3)) {
          console.log(' I ', i)
          // output the segment number and endpoints in the InfoWindow
          var origin = new Array()
          var destination = new Array()
          console.log('****************')
            for(let i=0;i<goldenGatePosition.length; i++){
              console.log(goldenGatePosition[i])
            }
            console.log('****************')
          console.log(segmentPolyline.getPath().getAt(0).address)
          origin.push(segmentPolyline.getPath().getAt(0).toUrlValue(6))
          destination.push(segmentPolyline.getPath().getAt(1).toUrlValue(6))
          const service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService(); // instantiate Distance Matrix service
      const matrixOptions = {
        origins: origin, // technician locations
        destinations: destination, // customer address
        travelMode: 'DRIVING',
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
      };
      // Call Distance Matrix service
      service.getDistanceMatrix(matrixOptions, callback);

      // Callback function used to process Distance Matrix response
      function callback(response, status) {
        console.log(response)
        console.log(status)
        if (status !== "OK") {
          alert("Error with distance matrix");
          return;
        }
        console.log(response);        
      }
          var content = "segment " + i + "<br>";
          content += "start of segment=" + segmentPolyline.getPath().getAt(0).toUrlValue(6) + "<br>";
          content += "end of segment=" + segmentPolyline.getPath().getAt(1).toUrlValue(6) + "<br>";
          infowindow.setContent(content);
          infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
          infowindow.open(map);
        }
      }
    });
}  
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAiybKuHI544-t5XPZzBGjQOBCO4MZFCwM&callback=myMap&libraries=geometry"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

When i click the polyline. How to get marker coordinates from polyline one end to another end.

Comment: When I use the posted code, I get the start and end coordinates of each polyline segment when I click on it. ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/9a6o0sdc/2/)) What is the issue?

Comment: @geocodezip . Can you please check my code. I will updated coordinates. This is the problem.

Comment: I still don't understand the problem.  You now have 5 markers in 2 groups of locations with a single polyline between each of them.  When I click on the polyline between any of the markers, it opens an `InfoWindow` with the correct coordinates in it. Can you clarify what you expect to happen that isn't happening?

Comment: @ geocodezip Different latitude and longitude. but it showing a single polyline and when I click polyline. It will show the segment 2 coordinates. remaining coordinate. I mean segment 0 coordinate, segment 1 coordinate, segment 2 coordinate, segment 3 coordinate,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tolerance in your call to `isLocationOnEdge` is too small.

> [**isLocationOnEdge**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry#poly.isLocationOnEdge)
> **isLocationOnEdge(point, poly[, tolerance])**
> **Parameters:**
> **point:**  LatLng
> **poly:**  Polygon|Polyline
> **tolerance:**  number optional
> **Return Value:***  boolean
> Computes whether the given point lies on or near to a polyline, or the edge of a polygon, within a specified tolerance. Returns true when the difference between the latitude and longitude of the supplied point, and the closest point on the edge, is less than the tolerance. The tolerance defaults to 10-9 degrees.

Your code:

```
if (google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(event.latLng, segmentPolyline, 10e-3)) {
```

Working value:

```
if (google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(event.latLng, segmentPolyline, 10e-7)) {
```

(when it is too large, it is picking up segment 1 for all locations on segment 0, as far as I can tell, all the other segments work correctly with your value)

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/9a6o0sdc/5/)

[image: screenshot showing correct infowindow on segment 0]

**code snippet:**

```js
function myMap() {
  var mapProp = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850),
    zoom: 5,
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (let i = 0; i < goldenGatePosition.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: goldenGatePosition[i],
      map: map,
      title: goldenGatePosition[i].address
    });
    if (i == 0 || i == 1) bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: goldenGatePosition,
    strokeColor: "#0000FF",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });
  flightPath.setMap(map);
  let poly, geodesicPoly;
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var codeStr = ''
  google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath, 'click', function(event) {
    // make polyline for each segment of the input line
    for (var i = 0; i < this.getPath().getLength() - 1; i++) {
      var segmentPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: [this.getPath().getAt(i), this.getPath().getAt(i + 1)]
      });
      console.log(segmentPolyline)
      // check to see if the clicked point is along that segment
      if (google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(event.latLng, segmentPolyline, 10e-7)) {
        console.log(' I ', i)
        // output the segment number and endpoints in the InfoWindow
        var origin = new Array()
        var destination = new Array()
        console.log('****************')
        for (let i = 0; i < goldenGatePosition.length; i++) {
          console.log(goldenGatePosition[i])
        }
        console.log('****************')
        console.log(segmentPolyline.getPath().getAt(0).address)
        origin.push(segmentPolyline.getPath().getAt(0).toUrlValue(6))
        destination.push(segmentPolyline.getPath().getAt(1).toUrlValue(6))
        const service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService(); // instantiate Distance Matrix service
        const matrixOptions = {
          origins: origin, // technician locations
          destinations: destination, // customer address
          travelMode: 'DRIVING',
          unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
        };
        // Call Distance Matrix service
        service.getDistanceMatrix(matrixOptions, callback);
        console.log("break")

        // Callback function used to process Distance Matrix response
        function callback(response, status) {
          console.log(response)
          console.log(status)
          if (status !== "OK") {
            alert("Error with distance matrix");
            return;
          }
          console.log(response);
        }
        var content = "segment " + i + "<br>";
        content += "start of segment=" + segmentPolyline.getPath().getAt(0).toUrlValue(6) + "<br>";
        content += "end of segment=" + segmentPolyline.getPath().getAt(1).toUrlValue(6) + "<br>";
        infowindow.setContent(content);
        infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
        infowindow.open(map);
      }
    }
  });
}
var goldenGatePosition = [{
  lat: 30.2179130,
  lng: -81.5628150,
  address: 'Tamil Nadu'
}, {
  lat: 30.2179140,
  lng: -81.5627480,
  address: 'India'
}, {
  lat: 30.2177650,
  lng: -81.5629100,
  address: 'America'
}, {
  lat: 30.2844080,
  lng: -81.5633900,
  address: 'Tamil Nadu'
}, {
  lat: 30.2843840,
  lng: -81.5633890,
  address: 'Tamil Nadu'
}];
```

```css
html,
body,
#googleMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="googleMap"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=myMap&libraries=geometry" defer></script>
```